# Search contract and web services

Tags: c#, search, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to come to grips with the search contract for Modern UI applications. In my particular case the items to search for come from a web based service so I'm hesitant to pull them all over the web and then let the user search the results for potentially a single match. My question is, how shall I go about that? Preferably, I'd just hook into the QuerySubmitted event and hit the web service from there, using the String from e.QueryText. Is that considered good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a simple server side search, then yes, hooking the **QuerySubmitted** event and passing the query text to your service is fine.  This assumes, of course, that your service supports that kind of lookup (i.e., it has a GetProductsByText rather than just a GetAllProducts).

Things get trickier if you want to use autocomplete and provide recommendations/suggestions to the user while they are typing by handing the **SuggestionsRequested** event.  In that case, start by looking at the [Search Contract Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5) for an example of how to handle that (in addition to being a good resource for understanding how tow work with the Search contract in general).

Answer (score 0):

You can even have a loot at https://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=1716 to have a better picture..!